# Phalcon redirect with new GET variables

Tags: php, redirect, phalcon

What is the best way to redirect to same page with new &_GET variables added.
I want to do something like Google done in Analytics, WMT...

Lets say user opens the page www.example.com, I would like to redirect that to
www.exaple.com?lang=en&uid=01845654&p=1.

Also, if someone enters www.example.com?p=2&lang=fr I would like to keep that variables, just add necessary one.

Should I do it in ControllerBase or in DI or somewhere else? And what is the pest proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something along the following lines from one of your controllers:

```
$destination = ltrim($this->di->get('router')->getMatchedRoute()->getPattern(), '/');
$queryString = 'lang=en&uid=01845654&p=1'
return $this->response->redirect($destination . '?' . $queryString);
```

For the problem of keeping incoming GET parameters and setting only those that have not been used in the request, you would have to check for them manually (e.g. using `$this->request->get(PARAM_NAME)`) and then build your query string accordingly.